# Spring Data Neo4j does not recognize externally inserted nodes

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using a small Clojure script which batch-inserts nodes to my Neo4j instance. 
To show these nodes, I am using a spring-based webapp with Spring Data Neo4j. 
I also created a small domain object which represents the node.

When I insert a node by utilizing the webapp, it will be loaded and showed right out of the box. But when I try to load a node which has been inserted by the external script, it cannot be found. To be compatible, I thought it is sufficient enough to add the **_*type*_** attribute with the FQN of the domain class. But it seems to me, that there's more to do.

I am using Neo4j 1.8.2 server and SDN 2.2.2

Can you give me a hint?

Thanks in advance.

Best,
Markus

Comment: Does Neo4j provides some kind of cache? Because it looks like your nodes inserted from a third-party application are not in the Web application cache and that's why it does not see them. if that's the case you need a single entry point or a way to invalidate you cache.

Comment: unfortunately I don't think, that this would help. Anybody correct me if I'm wrong. I have a loose guess, that it could have something to do with indexes, which will not be available under SDN. But honestly, I have no real clue for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) uses a [`TypeRepresentationStrategy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.2.x/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/core/TypeRepresentationStrategy.html). If SDN is not configured explicitely, it uses the [`IndexingNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.2.x/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/typerepresentation/IndexingNodeTypeRepresentationStrategy.html) and [`IndexingRelationshipTypeRepresentationStrategy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j/docs/2.2.x/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/support/typerepresentation/IndexingRelationshipTypeRepresentationStrategy.html) per default. These strategies keep an index named "__types__" for all its node entities and one named "__rel_types__" for all its relationship entities. All node or relationship entities that get created by SDN will be added to the corresponding index.

If you're using the repository infrastructure of SDN and call `yourEntityRepo.findAll()`, the  "__types__" (or "__rel_types__") index will be queried to get all your entities for this specific type.

Your script probably does not update those indices. Have a look at the [reindexing solution described on the neo4j google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/neo4j/bcije7z7tcE/Pcj-eBO7pP4J).